# Javascript error while dropping balls

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote a javascript code to drop in ball multiple times when clicked on canvas. It is an experiment.
Here is the code:
`HTML`

```
<br style="clear: both" />
<canvas id="myCanvas1" width="134px" height="331px" onclick="draw(0)"></canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas2" width="134px" height="331px" onclick="draw(1)"></canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas3" width="134px" height="331px" onclick="draw(2)"></canvas>
```

`JAVASCRIPT`

```
    var balls = [[], [], []],
    canvases = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas'),
    context = [],
    interval,
    boxWidth = 150,
    ballRadius = 10,
    canvasHeight = 235;
for (var i = 0; i < canvases.length; i++) {
    context.push(canvases[i].getContext('2d'));
}

function draw() {
    var movement = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        context[i].clearRect(0, 0, boxWidth, canvasHeight);
        for (var j = 0; j < balls[i].length; j++) {
            if (balls[i][j].y < balls[i][j].yStop) {
                balls[i][j].y += 4;
                movement = true;
            }
            context[i].beginPath();
            context[i].fillStyle = "red";
            context[i].arc(balls[i][j].x, balls[i][j].y, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
            context[i].closePath();
            context[i].fill();
        }
    }
    if (!movement) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        interval = null;
    }
}

function newBall(n) {
    console.log('new ball', n);
    var last = balls[n][balls[n].length - 1],
        ball = {x: ballRadius, y: ballRadius, yStop: canvasHeight - ballRadius};
    if (last) {
        if (last.x < boxWidth - ballRadius * 3) {
             ball.x = last.x + ballRadius * 2;
             ball.yStop = last.yStop;
        } else {
             ball.yStop = last.yStop - ballRadius * 2;
        }
    }
    balls[n].push(ball);
    if (!interval) {
        interval = setInterval(draw, 10);
    }
}
```

But balls aren't dropping in. Please tell me that where am I wrong so that I can fix it...

Comment: this question title is so epic :D till you come in here and actually read it :P

Comment: I had to set an epic title so that it can lure people ;)

Comment: Vote up this question so that I can mark question as complete

Comment: you can always pick correct answer no ?

Comment: I can't, unless I have repo points

Comment: Yes you can. Click the checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is always looping from 0 to 3. However, at first, there is no ball around. When you try to reach balls[0], balls[1] and balls[2], you get `undefined` error.

What you have to do is to change the loop to:

```
for (var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++)
```

or if you do not want to change the loop, you can initialize 3 balls at the start:

```
balls = [ball1, ball2, ball3];
```

where ball1, ball2 and ball3 are defined as how your ball data type is.

**EDIT:**

As I understand, you have some number of contexts, and for each context, you want to have a list of balls so that you can draw them.

Then:

```
balls = []

for (var i = 0; i < canvases.length; i++) {
    context.push(canvases[i].getContext('2d'));
    balls.push([]);
}
```

and use the remaining code same.

Comment: I did it and it returned another error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clearRect' of undefined` at the line  `context[i].clearRect(0, 0, boxWidth, canvasHeight);`

Comment: Since you have only 3 contexts, it gives an error again. If having 3 balls is the only case for you, then please try to initialize 3 balls at start.

Comment: You don't call `newBall(n)` function. Change onclick events from `draw(0)` to `newBall(0)`.

Comment: I did it, but balls aren't dropping in

Comment: Vote up this question so that I can mark question as complete.

Answer (score 3):

`balls` is `[]` when the loop starts. So `balls[0]` is undefined, and thus has no property `length`.

Comment: Set ```balls``` to something other than ```[]```. Maybe a list of objects with ```x``` and ```y``` properties?

Comment: Vote up this question so that I can mark question as complete