# Using div for dropping balls effect

Tags: javascript, html

Please check my old question:
[Old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26703896/javascript-error-while-dropping-balls)
In old question, I've used canvas for dropping balls effect. Can I use only `round shaped square divs` and implement ball dropping? I want to avoid usage of canvas.

Comment: bear in mind that using divs is generally much slower than canvas in most use cases

Answer (score 2):

You can use the CSS3 property `border-radius` to shape a square div into a round one. Using this property along with a `background` colour will render a round circle on the screen.

All you have to do is set `border-radius` to half the square length (set square length with `width` and `height` properties) and voila: you have a circle-shaped div.

If you want to support old browsers that don't support CSS3, then you can instead set the `background-image` property to a circle image.

http://jsfiddle.net/djvv1b1y/

You can set the position of the div by first setting the `position` property to `absolute`, then setting the `left` and `top` properties to offset the div from the top left corner of the ancestor positioned element (i.e. with a `position` property set to anything but `static`).

```
var round = document.getElementById('round');

// position and radius of circle
var x = 20, y = 20, r = 20;

// modifying CSS properties via DOM javascript 

// must be set in order to set the position of the circle
round.style.position = 'absolute';

// setting position
round.style.left = (x - r) + 'px';
round.style.top = (y - r) + 'px';

// setting diameter
round.style.width = (2 * r) + 'px';
round.style.height = (2 * r) + 'px';

// make square into a circle
round.style.borderRadius = r + 'px';

// colour
round.style.background = '#000';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/djvv1b1y/2/